# app.config doesn't save my config

Tags: c#, app-config

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["dbHost"].Value = txtHost.Text.ToString();
config.AppSettings.Settings["dbName"].Value = txtName.Text.ToString();
config.AppSettings.Settings["dbUser"].Value = txtUser.Text.ToString();
config.AppSettings.Settings["dbPass"].Value = txtPass.Text.ToString();
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

When I reopen application, I'm getting a blank text

Comment: Is the setting at Application or User level? If it is application, then this is expected behaviour I believe, as these cannot be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Applications are not supposed to change the app.config within the setup/bin directory during run-time, only during setup-time. During run-time, applications are supposed to write to application folder under %APPDATA% folder. If you have UAC active, Windows will enforce this.

Also, the API you used isn't meant to modify the file.

If you want to access the %APPDATA% settings (per user), use this PerUserRoaming or PerUserRoamingAndLocal instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationuserlevel.aspx

Comment: What can I save settings? ini? If I use ini file, It's not safe. even if it is encrypted

Comment: 1. You can save settings in config files; user.config files, not app.config files. 2. What do you mean by "safe"? Config files are usually not encrypted either.

Comment: I want connect to remote mysql server and I should hide connection string. But connection string should be updated on runtime. I use ini file now. Ex: my ini file includes user=BoQ2cnMoyi+jP0/e7Pnxjg== on [db] property. But other persons can decrypt it. Where do you hide db settings?

Comment: If database is remote, use user claims to connect. If you don't wasn't user to access database directly, go through a remote service which user logs in to - do not connect to database from user machine. If database is on user machine, then you have a problem preventing that user from accessing directly - Whatever encryption you use, key is stored on user machine, so user can find it by decompiling app's code.